# Subsetting image such as NAIP?

Tags: raster, compression, mrsid

Has anyone any luck subsetting a small part out from NAIP?

I seek your feedback on pros or cons of how to subset an image from NAIP despite they are in mrsid and their uncompressed file size are hefty size.

What software do you use and why do you use it when you subset them?

Comment: I simply used ArcGIS and clip. However I found that unless the area was extremely small, there was no real advantage in terms of file size savings or access time. Even a small portion (say 10%) saved compressed tiff ended up being the same size or a little larger that the original MrSID.

Comment: Yes, I agreed the smaller the better can do that however if you want larger area to subset it takes a few hours to run it with ArcGIS.